# Bootstrap card with stretched link - tooltips in the card no longer work

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Using Bootstrap 4.3, I created a card element with a tooltip inside. This works fine.

However when I add a stretched link to the card ([reference](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/stretched-link/)) then the tooltip no longer works.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

Here is a code example of the scenario where the tooltip doesn't work:

```
<div class="card ">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Meeting Cancelled</h5>
      <p class="card-text">
        Alex has cancelled your meeting.
      </p>
    </div>
    <span class="time" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="17 July 2019, 11:39">39 minutes ago</span>
  </div>
  <a class="stretched-link" href="http://localhost:3000/my/meetings"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Your stretched link covers the whole of the card so you cannot mouse over anything under it.  If you want to link the whole card then move your anchor to wrap the content instead (eg instead of using the div with a class of card, you could use the anchor with a class of card)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @Pete.
This gave me an idea, and after fiddling with the tooltip's z-index I could get it "above" the link, and it triggers the tooltip. This means the link won't be triggered on a click, but I'm fine with that.

Answer (score 0):

Please check snippet it working with in stretched link, look like you missing js or you need to add tooltip function.

```js
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<div class="card ">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Meeting Cancelled</h5>
      <p class="card-text">
        Alex has cancelled your meeting.
      </p>
    </div>
    <span class="time" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="17 July 2019, 11:39">39 minutes ago</span>
  </div>
  <a class="stretched-link" href="http://localhost:3000/my/meetings"></a>
</div>
```